# Deleting SQLCommand throwing inadequate exception

Tags: c#, debugging, datagridview, sqlcommand

I have virtual dataGridView which displays all values in table by Just-In-Time method [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.110).aspx). My view has more computed columns, so I use it only to show data and then only delete by single SQLCommand.
The problem comes when I am executing the delete command. When I execute it, it throws error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TextValueFromThirdColumn' to data type int.

xxx is not ID, but computed data in third column.

```
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
     {
          c.Open();
          SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("delete from entryTable where ID = @id", c);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

[image: added parameter]

As you can see I am building query with parameter which adds just fine, but the error thrown seems inadequate for me, because third column has nothing to do with my ID column. Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Can you just change it to this:
Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())

Comment: i think you have set the `ID` as your primary key, I dont think it allows your to delete it, but you can `REPLACE` it I believe., if not maybe you can change your `ID` column to an INT that have auto increments on, so that you dont have to manually add the int key.

Comment: @McGaz the ID adds fine, as you can see in the screenshot, I don't think this is problem with parameter. Now when I tried it, it throws the same error

Comment: @Werdna Nope, the `ID` column is just `Identity(1,1)` and primary key is another 2 columns

Comment: ok, can you change the `ID` column type to `INT`

Comment: It already is `int`. I don't think it would even allow me to make any other datatype autoincrement.

Comment: So 153 is not the ID of the record you want to delete?

Comment: @McGaz sorry to bother you, the code works just right. Check answer for details.

Comment: No worries, just checking things out whilst my code builds. Glad its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, It was my dumb fault. This is problem with trigger on SQL server. I did not realize I made changes to database layout and trigger stopped working because it inserted values into wrong column. The error code showed what happened with trigger, not with row.